# На каком беспалатном хостинге для discord бота можно использовать json для системы лвлов?

Tags: python, json, discord.py, hosting

Я использую на данный момент heroku но он не поддерживает удобное чтение и запись json файлов!
Хотел бы найти такой хостинг на котором используются файлы на github'е а не создают на своём сервере папку с файлами!

Comment: Ничего вообще не ясно. Можно детальнее?

Comment: Я использую heroku но хочу добавить в своего discord бота систему лвлов но для этого нужно постоянно записывать и считывать данные из json файла а heroku не поддерживает чтение и запись файлов с github'а поэтому я спрашиваю есть ли хостинги которые используют файлы с github и могут записывает данные в json

Comment: возможно 000webhost.com спасет вашу ситуацию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ладно хорошо я попробую зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

`Heroku` не умеет сохранять данные, а работает с ними пока запущен процесс.
Можно попробовать работать напрямую с файлами на `GitHub`

Принцип примерно такой:

1. Загружаем все нужные json-файлы на `GitHub`
2. **[`pip install PyGithub`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/)**, **[`Документация`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)**
3. Пишем код для работы с файлами:

**Получаем данные**

```
import json
from github import Github
from urllib.request import urlopen

TOKEN = 'token' # токен можно получить на GitHub
g = Github(TOKEN)
repo = g.get_user().get_repo("repository-name")
our_file = repo.get_contents("our.json")
try:
    data = urlopen(our_file.download_url).read()
    jsondata = json.loads(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Ошибка при получении our.json : {e}')
    jsondata = []
```

**Сохраняем данные**

```
def save_file(comment):
    global jsondata, our_file
    data = json.dumps(jsondata, ensure_ascii = False, indent = 4)
    repo.update_file("our.json", comment, data, our_file.sha)
    our_file = repo.get_contents("our.json")

save_file('комментарий')
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно но я нашёл другой способ решения!

Comment: Я задумывался сделать как то так но нашёл более лёгкий способ!